# Blender 3.1 Combining Two Bone's Tails Together

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent

So, I've seen a lot of info on how to combine two *HEADS* of bones together, but what I need is two *TAILS*.  I'm assuming that I would need another bone where the two tails are to combine them, but I can't seem to find a way to combine them there.  This is what I'm working on, a hood to a jacket where I want the hood to be rigged:

Here it is with no Bones
[image: Hood No Bones]

Here is my current Armature:
[image: Hood Bones]

And this is how I think it should work in my head, but it seems like you can't connect one bone to two bones:
[image: What I'm Thinking]

Any ideas?  I tried making the top bone a child of the other two bones, but that didn't seem to work, as it would only be affected by the first child of constraint in the list.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, could you please explain what you're trying to achieve with these bones?

Comment: I'm using the armature to more accurately shape the coat and hood, as cloth simulations just weren't cutting it.  As for the reason I want to combine the tails of the bones at the top, since the bone chains meet at the same vertexes on the top, it just made sense to me to attach them together.  I might also use the extra bone on the top (the third picture) to do some IK to make the hood fold forward and back.

Comment: yes I was thinking about giving an IK constraint to the bones, then the top one is the controller

Comment: YES!  This was exactly what I needed.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I put an IK modifier on both of the top bones, which were Hood Left Edge.002 and Hood Right Edge.002, and used the one I wanted to attach them to as the controller/Target Bone, which was Hood Tip.

Here's what that looked like, with Hood Tip being the new bone on top:
[image: IK Setup]

Comment: it's not modifier but constraint  ;)

Comment: Oops!  Thanks.  Updated the answer.